# Query with Union all and order by

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have this query to merge two DE in SFMC and I need to merge also the email duplicates inside. I have a syntax error near 'x' that I cannot find.

```
Select top 1 with ties

x.Email

from (

Select
a.Email, 
a.Subscriber_Key,
a.CreatedDate, 
a.First_Name,
a.Last_Name

from [AllAccount_DedupEmail_Last_Test] a

union all 
  
Select 
b.Email, 
b.Subscriber_Key,
b.CreatedDate, 
b.First_Name,
b.Last_Name
from [Leads_ALL_sans_doublons] b

) x

order by row_number() over (partition x.Email order by x.CreatedDate desc)
```

Can you provide some help ?

Comment: This question has received a number of votes stating that it's off-topic for Salesforce Stack Exchange. I don't agree - in my opinion, just like JavaScript applied within a Salesforce context is on-topic, so too is SQL applied in a Marketing Cloud context. If you feel strongly in the other direction, let's start a conversation on Meta!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `by` after your `partition`:

```sql
Select top 1 with ties

x.Email

from (

Select
a.Email, 
a.Subscriber_Key,
a.CreatedDate, 
a.First_Name,
a.Last_Name

from [AllAccount_DedupEmail_Last_Test] a

union all 
  
Select 
b.Email, 
b.Subscriber_Key,
b.CreatedDate, 
b.First_Name,
b.Last_Name
from [Leads_ALL_sans_doublons] b

) x

order by row_number() over (partition by x.Email order by x.CreatedDate desc)
```

Comment: Indeed :D thanks a lot Adam :)